# Pdf does not showing product image? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

When printing the order pdf, product image is not showing. When I var dump the imagePath I get result:

```
string(150) "http://mysite/media/catalog/product/cache/15/thumbnail/75x75/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/b/j/bj9660_02_reebok_les_mills_zenski_sorc.jpg"
```

This is the code that returns an image:

```
$image = [
      'items_small_image' => [
      'value' => '<img src="' . $imagePath . '" />',
      'label' => __('Product image'),
   ],
];
```

But, when I hard code the image path the the image is showing:

```
$image = [
      'items_small_image' => [
      'value' => '<img src="http://mysite/media/catalog/product/cache/15/thumbnail/75x75/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/b/j/bj9660_02_reebok_les_mills_zenski_sorc.jpg" />',
      'label' => __('Product image'),
   ],
];
```

What is the problem with variable? Did anybody had the same issue?